# How to stop SwiftUI from changing font sizes automatically

Tags: swiftui, fonts, font-size, dynamic-type-feature

I using text like this in SwiftUI

```
Text("Customize").font(.footnote)
```

But this is also changing the font size base of device font size settings.

So how I stop SwiftUI to change the default font size automatically?

PS: I don't want to set all Texts font size manually.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a Font extension like this:

```
import SwiftUI

extension Font {
    static var appButton:Font {
        get {
            return .system(size: 18)
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it as:

```
Text("Observation mode")
.font(.appButton)
```

Answer (score -1):

**Hey! Please Give It A Try!**

```
Text("Customize").font(.system(size: 32))
```

Comment: Thank you @Dc7, but this way I have to modify all the texts I used, & I don't want to do that. you know, we sat all the text font sizes base of defaults iOS sizes like (title, caption, footnote, etc) & we don't want to change them.

Comment: You can try this
Text("NewText").font(.medium)